# What is the logic behind this answer?

Tags: exponential-function

$$9^x = 2 \times  3^{x}+6$$

The method in my book to solve this:

$$(3^2)^x = 2 \times 3^x + 6$$

$$(3^x)^2 = 2 \times 3^x + 6$$

$$ p=3^x, p^2=2p+6$$

After using quadratic equation we get the answers ($x = \log_3(1+\sqrt{7})$)

This bothers me:

- Why does $(3^2)^x = (3^x)^2$, this seems incorrect to me (LHS = $9^x$ and RHS = $9^{xx}$)

Comment: $\left(a^b\right)^c=a^{bc}=a^{cb}=\left(a^c\right)^b$

Comment: Multiplication is commutative...

Comment: Your RHS is incorrect. You put down $9^{xx}$, which is $9^{(x^2)}$, not $(9^x)^2$.

Comment: I think Brian M. Scott's comment is more to the point than Fant's is.  You can't use commutativity of multiplication until what you've got is multiplication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure what kind of answer you are looking for, but perhaps this will help:  $$\left(3^{x}\right)^{2}=3^{x}\cdot3^{x}=3^{x+x}=3^{2x} $$ and $$\left(3^{2}\right)^{x}=\left(3\cdot3\right)^{x}=3^{x}\cdot3^{x}=3^{2x}.$$

In general, $$\left(x^y\right)^z=x^{yz}=(x^z)^y.$$

Comment: Note: This law only holds if the base/power are real... http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentLaws.html

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following theorems (with proofs): [Power of Power](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_Combination_Laws/Power_of_Power) and [Power of Product](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_Combination_Laws/Power_of_Product). These results should help you understand the concepts better. Needless to say, real multiplication is commutative.

Answer (score 1):

http://hotmath.com/hotmath_help/topics/properties-of-exponents.html here is a pretty good collection of examples and explanations to your problem. it is a simple property of exponents.